# How to find which control made the asyncpostback?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I know how to find which control made the postback, it's something like:

```
string postBackControl = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET") == null ? string.Empty : Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
```

but how can I find the one that made async postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this...

[Which control raised the async postback event?](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/12/12/which-control-raised-the-async-postback-event.aspx)